# redirect https url without www to https url with www in web.config

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module, web-config-transform

Can any one tell me about how to redirect https url without www to https url with www in web.config file.

Here is some code that I have tried but I didn't meet my requirement.

```
<rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="<www.url>/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">    
               <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false"/>    
               <conditions>    
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off"/>    
               </conditions>    
               <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>    
            </rule>
```